# DatePicker JQUERY UI - Remarcar fechas de una base de datos

Tags: javascript, ajax, base-de-datos, datepicker, jquery-ui

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es remarcar algunas fechas, sacadas de una base de datos, en un datepicker. Después de buscar mucho por internet parece algo normal, pero no lo consigo.. cualquier ayuda será bienvenida.

Mis codigos:

```
//función para mostrar el calendario (datepicker jquery ui)
function calendario() {

var fechas = [];

//recuperar el idobra seleccionado
var idobra = $("#combo_obra").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "php/consulta_clientes.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {"idobra":idobra, "opcion":"remarcar"},
    success: function(respuesta) {

        var arrayRespuesta = JSON.parse(respuesta);

        for(var i = 0; i<arrayRespuesta.length; i++) {

            fechas[new Date (arrayRespuesta[i]["fecha"])] = new Date (arrayRespuesta[i]["fecha"]);
        }
        return fechas;
    }
})
console.log(fechas);

$('#calendario').datepicker({
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    prevText: '< Ant',
    nextText: 'Sig >',
    firstDay: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    currentText: 'Hoy',

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        console.log(date);
        console.log(fechas);

        var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
            if($.inArray(date, fechas) !== -1) {
                return [true, 'verde'];
            } else {
                 return [true, ''];
            }
    }
})
```

};

He puesto tres console.log para ver que hay.

El primero después de la consulta $.ajax, donde se ve un array con las fechas que quiero remarcar en el calendario:

[image: 1]

El segundo dentro de beforeShowDay, para ver el parametro date (en el console log original aparecen algunas lineas de fechas más):

[image: 2]

Y el tercero también dentro de beforeShowDay para asegurar que el array fechas llega:

[image: 3]

El calendario en si mismo lo visualizo perfectamente, traducido al castellano incluso, dentro de un div con id="calendario".

Creo que el problema está en el formato de las fechas o zonas horarias, porque al hacer "$.inArray(date, fechas) !== -1" todo me entra por el else (al hacer un console.log de $.inArray(date, fechas) todo es igual a -1)

En cualquier caso por más que le doy vueltas no consigo que funcione, alguna idea?? Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida, gracias de antemano.

--- EDITO

Un caso similar es el expuesto en esta página, que también lo he visto por stackoverflow, en este caso lo hacen con un array escrito en vez de venir de una base de datos. Y esto si me funciona; pero si pongo mi array fechas (que sale de $.ajax) en eventDates[date] obtengo el mismo resultado que con mi código anterior.

https://programacion.net/articulo/como_resaltar_fechas_especificas_en_jquery_ui_datepicker_1731

--- EDITO (comentario azeós - PD. gracias por tus ideas)

Modifico el array fechas para que sea string

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/consulta_clientes.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {"idobra":idobra, "opcion":"remarcar"},
    success: function(respuesta) {
        //json a array asociativo
        var arrayRespuesta = JSON.parse(respuesta);

        for(var i = 0; i<arrayRespuesta.length; i++) {

            fechas[i] = arrayRespuesta[i]["fecha"];
        }
        return fechas;
    }
})

console.log(fechas);
```

[image: 4]

He puesto guiones en el formato para que sea igual al resultado del array fechas var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

        //console.log(date);
        //console.log(fechas[0]); //undefined
        console.log(fechas);

            if($.inArray(date, fechas) !== -1) {
                return [true, 'verde'];

            } else {
                 return [true, ''];
            }
    }
```

Console.logs hechos dentro de beforeShowDay:

Console.log date (faltan lineas de fechas en la imagen):

[image: 5]

Console.log fechas:

[image: 6]

Y como he comentado en comentarios console.log(fechas[0]) es undefined, porque? no deberia ser 2017-12-04??

Comment: `$.inArray(date, eventDates)` no debería ser `$.inArray(date, fechas)`? No tenés declarado el array `eventDates` en ningún lado.

Comment: si, es fechas. ahora mismo lo cambio en la pregunta. ese no es el problema. seguramente está pq he estado provando con el código del enlace que he adjuntado

Comment: El problema, como sospechas, está en el formato de las fechas. Hacé un `console.log` de una fecha X (`fechas[0]`) y de `date`. Si no tienen el mismo formato, no van a coincidir nunca. Si el array `fechas` sólo lo estás usando para esto, te diría que directamente cuando lo armas en la consulta AJAX ya le pongas el formato que vas a usar en el datepicker (`yy/mm/dd`).

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses una librería para manipular las fechas: [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Las fechas del array ya salen en yy/mm/dd, pero por ejemplo el 4 de diciembre que está tanto en el array fechas como en date:
en fechas es: Date 2017-12-04T00:00:00.000Z
y en date es: Date 2017-12-04T23:00:00.000Z
eso es un problema??

Comment: Los console log estan publicados arriba, tanto del array fechas como de date. Y no tengo fechas[0] pq en el enlace que adjunto ponen la fecha también como indice del array.. no se pq, así que lo que tengo es fechas[fecha en cuestion] = fecha en cuestion

Comment: El `console.log(date)` que tenés está ANTES de asignarle un nuevo valor `var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);`. Ponelo después de esa línea para ver bien que genera. Y si, si no son iguales, es un problema. Por eso lo más fácil es que no guardes dentro del array un objeto `Date` sino directamente un `string` con la fecha.

Comment: Me parece acertado lo que comentas y tienes razón, pero no acabo de conseguirlo. Con "var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date)" transformo el objeto date en strings, así que he cambiado la función success de $.ajax para que también sea string, para q sean iguales. Ahora dentro de beforeShowDay llega el array fechas (se ve en un console.log) pero me sale undefined si hago console.log(fechas[0]). Parece absurdo pero hay algo q no veo.. (ahora añado las modificaciones de codigo e imagenes arriba)

Comment: fechas[0] es undefined desde despues de "return fechas;" de $.ajax, y obviamente también lo es en beforeShowDay. El array fechas lo he formado así "fechas[i] = arrayRespuesta[i]["fecha"];" pero es lo mismo q hacerlo con array push "fechas.push(arrayRespuesta[i]["fecha"]);" mismo resultado. Así que supongo q el problema ahora, además de lo q ya me has solucionado (muchas gracias por ello), está en sacar el array fechas de $.ajax.. alguna idea de q está mal??

Comment: No entiendo porque dentro del `beforeShowDay` el `console.log(fechas)` devuelve lo correcto pero no `fechas[0]`. El punto es que si el datepicker tiene que crearse si o si después de haber obtenido `fechas` de la consulta por AJAX, entonces deberías mover todo el código del datepicker dentro del `success` del AJAX. Probá eso y vemos, porque puede ser que se esté ejecutando primero el datepicker y después el AJAX, pero entonces el `console.log` debería mostrar otra cosa.

Comment: No se que pasa con console.log(fechas[0]), sigue siendo undefined fuera del $.ajax (apesar de verse bien console.log(fechas)). Pero al meter el datapicker dentro de success todo lo demás funciona perfectamente, se me marcan los dias al cargarse el calendario. MUCHAS GRACIAS :D